# What causes weapons to become unusable?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

In combat challenge maps, there may be weapons for the enemies to use. I've noticed that over time, the enemies stop using some of them.

I've been constantly taking out enemies that have picked up the stun stick, the car door, or the firearm with the hope that they won't pick up the weapon again, but constantly causing them to drop the weapon seems to make no difference. Whether or not causing them to drop the weapon helps matters because the effort it takes to disarm them puts me at risk and if causing them to drop the weapon doesn't make a difference, I could spend the time that I use to disarm them attacking other enemies. Efficient use of time is important in Joker's Carnival, which is the challenge that I'm playing.

What causes the enemies to stop picking up weapons and using them? Time since the weapon was introduced? Time held/used? A bug?

Answer (score 2):

If an enemy is within a certain range of the weapon, they'll pick it up. If the fight is drawn away from the weapons, the AI will not focus on them, as they are too far away.

After some levelling up, you can gain an upgrade to destroy the weapon as part of a take-down combo, making it permanently unusable.

Comment: http://youtu.be/TldMhUbPLIM